# Windows Phone 8 app update, install issue

Tags: windows-phone-8, updates, marketplace

I recently published new version of my Windows Phone 8 app. Now when I update the app from store, the app downloads fine and install goes almost to end. However the install fails, it says "attention required". If I tap this, I get message "We're having trouble installing this app. Tap and hold the item, then tap Retry. If you are updating existing app, and the problem continues, you might need to uninstall the app then reinstall it again." When I tap retry, it installs fine (at least with my two devices).

What can cause this, and how I can avoid this in next update?

The update was actually small change, just one more value to store to isolated storage, and something other minor.

Comment: It happened on every device you tried? Or was it just a glitch on one device?

Comment: attention required may be raised when you have connection problem too.

Comment: By now, I have tried this with two devices, both had the same issue. I think this is not connection issue, as the downlaod went fine and the problem occurs when app is installing.